# The conjugacy class of $H<G$ is equipotent to the set of right/left cosets of $N_G(H)$ in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here is how I would prove the statement.

I need to find a bijection between $A=\{H^a =a^{-1}Ha|a\in G\}$, the conjugacy class of $H<G$, and $B=\{a*N_G(H)|a\in G\}$, the set of left cosets of $N_G(H)$ in $G$.

Let $f$ be the function $f:A\rightarrow B$ such that $a^{-1}Ha\mapsto a*N_G(H)$.

- $f$ is surjective

$\forall a*N_G(H) \in B$, $f(a^{-1}Ha)=a*N_G(H)$

- $f$ is injective

Let $a^{-1}Ha$ and $b^{-1}Hb$ be elements of $A$ such that $f(a^{-1}Ha)=f(b^{-1}Hb)$ $\Rightarrow$ $a*N_G(H)=b*N_G(H)$

How do I go on from here? How do I prove that $a=b$ ?

[EDIT]

I thought this was an easier way to prove it.

Let $g:G\rightarrow Cl(H)$ be a map from the group $G$ to the conjugacy classes of $H<G$ such that $x\mapsto H^x=x^{-1}Hx$.

This is clearly a homeomorphism and the kernel of $g$ is $N_G(H)$.

So, for the homeomorphism theorem I have that $\frac{G}{N_G(H)}\cong Cl(H)\Rightarrow card(\frac{G}{N_G(H)})=card(Cl(H))\Rightarrow $ the conjugacy class of $H<G$ is equipotent to the set of right/left cosets of $N_G(H)$ in $G$.

Does this proof work?

Comment: This follows directly from the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem, by letting $G$ act on the lattice of subgroups via conjugation, and considering the orbit of $H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your chosen bijection works more smoothly if you use right cosets $N_G(H)a$.

Define $f:A \to B$ by $f(a^{-1}Ha) = N_G(H)a$. As you said, this is clearly surhective. We have
$$ a^{-1}Ha=b^{-1}Hb \Leftrightarrow ba^{-1}Hab^{-1} = H \Leftrightarrow ba^{-1} \in N_G(H) \Leftrightarrow N_G(H)a=N_G(H)b.$$

Note that the forward implications imply that $f$ is well-defined, and the reverse implications show that it is injective.